# Use DOB from mysql DB to determine child/adult

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my query to search the data base for candidates who meet a certain criteria. I am using php, mysql, html

```
$Odata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE(`gender` LIKE '%".$Gender."%')
     AND (`verbal`  LIKE '%".$Verbal."%') AND(`waiver`  LIKE '%".$Waiver."%')
     AND(`waiver_type`  LIKE '%".$W_Type."%') AND(`sel_staff`  LIKE '%".$A_Staff."%')
     AND(`sel_peers` LIKE '%".$A_Peers."%')AND(`verbal`  LIKE '%".$Awake."%')
     AND(`ambulatory`  LIKE '%".$Ambulatory."%') AND(`function`  LIKE '%".$Function."%')"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

There is another criteria I want to add - Adult/Child.
I have date of birth as a column in the DB. If the candidate is above 18, would fall under Adult, otherwise Child.

The user may want to search for an adult with all the contents in $Odata. How can I do this?

looking through [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb)
and [Search age range in mysql, php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611178/search-age-range-in-mysql-php) I understand it can be done independently, but how can I incorporate it into my above query. Is that possible?

Comment: off your question topic, but you might like to consider changing to mysqli /PDO functions because the mysql_* ones are depreciated.  Would also be worth reading about prepared statements and sql injections.

Comment: I'd like to find the function `foo%'; --`

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,date_of_birth,CURDATE()) will give current age if `date_of_birth` is a `timestamp` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

**sample data**

```
create table dob
( 
    dob datetime
  ) 
;
insert into dob select '2001-10-08' ;
insert into dob select '1976-11-28' ;
```

**Figure out child or adult:**

```
select 
 dob, 
 case when dob  > Current_date() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR then 'child' else 'adult' end
from dob
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2df6d/12

Comment: I don't know how mySQL handles stuff like this, but you'd probably be better off using `dob > Current_date() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR`, as the optimizer then has a (more easily recognizable) chance at performing the date math _once_, as opposed to for every row.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Kenny, I think that is what I will do!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a correct answer in the [official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE()) >=18 THEN 'adult' ELSE 'child' END
FROM p_candidate;
```